# Generic Akka ActorSystem

Tags: scala, akka

Is there any way to create `ActorSystem[T]` which will create only `actors <:T` ? For all other types it could throw exception or something like this.

Comment: No, there is no such thing. What's the use case?

Answer (score 0):

Typed Actors: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/typed-actors.html.

Citing documentation: "The advantage of Typed Actors vs. Actors is that with TypedActors you have a static contract, and don't need to define your own messages, the downside is that it places some limitations on what you can do and what you can't, i.e. you cannot use become/unbecome."

Comment: I have remote ActorSystem and several clients which can create actors in this system. But I should be sure that no one client creates any undesirable actor type. I don't think that typed actors solve this problem.